# struct passed by in ref to foreign function has unset fields

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke, ref

c header extract:

```c
struct GetArgvOptions {
  uint      skip;
  pid_t     pid;
  bool      nuls;
};
bool get_argv_of_pid(const struct GetArgvOptions* options, struct ArgvResult* result);
```

c# classlib extract:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct GetArgvOptions {
    public nuint skip;
    public nint  pid;
    public bool  nuls;
}
[DllImport("libgetargv.dylib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool get_argv_of_pid(in GetArgvOptions options, out ArgvResult result);
```

c# unit test extract:

```cs
int pid = Environment.ProcessId;
GetArgvOptions opt;
opt.pid = pid;
opt.skip = 0;
opt.nuls = false;
Console.WriteLine($"pid: {opt.pid}");
ArgvResult res = new ArgvResult();
bool success = get_argv_of_pid(in opt, out res);
```

The `get_argv_of_pid` function sees an option struct with pid set to 0 not the actual pid, the line printed to the console confirms the pid is set before the struct is passed to the function.

Comment: `nuint` is wrong, should be `uint`

Comment: `skip` and `pid` => `uint` or `int`. `options` and `result` should be passed using `ref`. `SetLastError` is useless (for Windows API that document using it only)

Comment: @SimonMourier why ref instead of in and out? Moreover it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: @Charlieface can you write an answer about why nuint doesn't work in ffi/pinvoke structs? Especially if you can link to some docs... you're right of course, but i wish i knew why a system sized uint is wrong...

Comment: ref passes by pointer, in by value. C# nuint is wrong because its size depends on 32 vs 64-bit process architecture, while C's uint and pid_t are always 32-bit.

Comment: @SimonMourier `in` is also passed by pointer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`uint` and `pid_t` in C are both 32-bit, always. Whereas `nint` and `nuint` are dependent on the processor native width. So you need to change them to `uint` and `int` respectively.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct GetArgvOptions {
    public uint skip;
    public int  pid;
    public bool  nuls;
}
```